# how to append two strings in javascript without space?

Tags: javascript

I have two strings one brings me a time ie:

```
var gettime= $("#select-choice-2 :selected").text();
```

it gives me time in 24 hr format like this

```
17:45
```

but i want my time to be in a format like

```
17:45:00.000
```

for which i made a string

```
var ext=':00.000';
```

I want these two strings to concatenate in such a way to give me proper result.

**I see now whats the problem is my "gettime" is not a proper string, i tried it to show in alertbox but nothing happens, so please tell me how to convert gettime into a string.**

**I got it "gettime" is a local variable and ext is using in some other function thats why "gettime" was not appearing in alertbox, stupid ehh :p**

Comment: have you tried `gettime + ext` ?

Comment: What do you mean without space? There is no space

Comment: I see now whats the problem is my "gettime" is not a proper string, i tried it to show in alertbox but nothing happens, so please tell me how to convert gettime into a string.

Comment: @priyankirk show your website or make a jsfiddle. If you don't get an alert it's because you have an error in your scripts, not because it's not a string. So check your console for errors as well.

Comment: The selector and code [seems fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9rFBS/). Might be due to an error somewhere else as as @Esailija said.

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté @Esailija got it "gettime" is a local variable and ext is using in some other function thats why "gettime" was not appearing in alertbox!
thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: scope problems.. you can submit it as an answer to don't leave it unanswered I guess.

Comment: So this question had nothing to do with "how to concatenate strings" (that would be weird since if you know the word concatenate, you can probably google for it anyway) :P

Comment: How to delete this question? :p

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the concatenation operator:

```
alert( gettime + ext );
```

Comment: I see now whats the problem is my "gettime" is not a proper string, i tried it to show in alertbox but nothing happens, so please tell me how to convert gettime into a string.

Comment: `gettime.toString() + ...` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Maybe it's `null` or empty? `.text()` should return a string. Make sure your selector is returning the right object and that it has text nodes to be retrieved with `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just wand to add the strings together?
In that case:

```
var bothstrings = gettime + ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

some browsers can cause line-breaks to the resulting string if you directly assign a `+` between strings to joing them. The standard way to do is -

```
gettime.concat(ext)
```

Comment: var joinString=gettime.concat(ext); //joinString=17:45:00.000

Answer (score 0):

**
scope problem,i get it now. gettime was a local variable within some function and ext is held in different function thats why in the function gettime is not appearing in alertbox **